# Do Cylon Leaders in Battlestar Galactica (Daybreak expansion) draw an extra card in sickbay?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I recently played a game of BSG with some friends and we ran into a situation wherein the Cylon Leader was in the sickbay and their turn came around. The sickbay states that you draw only one card, but they argued that the infiltration card from the Daybreak expansion gives them an extra card.

The rule book text is not so clear on this situation, so I'm hoping someone can clarify.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, Cylon Leaders are restricted to one card in Sickbay.

From the [Daybreak rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/daybreak/BSG_Daybreak_rulebook_engindd_v-3.pdf)

> An Infiltrating Cylon Leader draws one extra Skill Card from
>   within his Skill set during his “Receive Skills” step for a total of
>   three Skill Cards.

Hence, they only receive an extra card if they are receiving their normal 2 cards.  Sickbay overrides it to only allow one card per character in Sickbay.

The rules also note that the Infiltration card is a "summary" of the Infiltration rules.